# How to make selected letters bold within URL?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a `<span>` or `<a href...>` element and I want to make some of it's letters bold, for example (STACK is bolded):

```
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">**STACK**OVERFLOW.COM></a>
```

And some of the email clients would ignore `<strong>`:

```
<p><strong>STACK</strong>OVERFLOW.COM</p>
```

redirecting the user to www.overflow.com

In other words, putting `<b>` or `<strong>` breaks the string into separate ones

How can I make it? A simple word with few letters**bold**

Comment: `<a href="www.stackoverflow.com"><b>STACK</b>OVERFLOW.COM></a>` This is the proper way, that means you need to split the string yes or yes.

Comment: "Breaks the string into separate ones"? What do you mean with this? What is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: I want to have one string of text where some of it's letters are bold. But using tags like <b> or <strong> causes annoyances, such as weird behaviour for :hover or, as mentioned, in gmail redirecting to the wrong domain (treating bolded letters as not-the-part-of-the-url>

Answer (score 1):

```css
a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 24px;
}

a span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"><span>STACK</span>OVERFLOW.COM</a>
```

Comment: He is asking if there is another way without separating the string inside the a

Comment: No, <b> and <strong> can't be used.

Comment: Tested right now, gmail, thunderbird, Outlook 2008 and Outlook 2016 `<b>` element works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a span tag inside of the anchor tag without issue:

```html
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com"><span style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">STACK</span>OVERFLOW.COM</a>
```

Comment: He is asking if there is another way without separating the string inside the `a`

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question **yes**, you are forced to split the text in two to indicate which part you want on bold, because you need to add the desired bold text inside the `b` element.

Then understanding this, the proper way to do is is like this:

```
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com"><b>STACK</b>OVERFLOW.COM></a>
```